# AvroTypeException when reading from internal Hive Table with nested Structs

Tags: hive, avro, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

I work on a Azure HDInsight cluster with version 3.6. It uses Hortonworks HDP 2.6, which comes with Hive 2.1.0 (on Tez 0.8.4).

I have some internal Hive tables with nested struct fields stored in Avro format. Here is one example CREATE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE my_example_table(
    some_field STRING,
    some_other_field STRING,
    some_struct struct<field1: BIGINT, inner_struct struct<field2: STRING, field3: STRING>>)
PARTITIONED BY (year INT, month INT)
STORED AS AVRO;
```

I populate these tables with from an external table which also is stored as avro, like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE my_example_table
PARTITION (year, month)
SELECT ....
FROM my_external_table;
```

When I want to query the internal tables I got the following error: `Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found core.record_0, expecting union`

I extracted the avro schema from one of these internal tables with the Avro tools and recognized that Hive creates union types from the structs I defined:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "my_example_table",
  "namespace" : "my_namespace",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "some_field",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "some_other_field",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "my_struct",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "record_0",
      "namespace" : "",
      "doc" : "struct<field1: BIGINT, struct<field2: STRING, field3: STRING>>",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "field1",
        "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
        "doc" : "bigint",
        "default" : null
      }, {
        "name" : "inner_struct",
        "type" : [ "null", {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "record_2",
          "namespace" : "",
          "doc" : "struct<field2: STRING, field3: STRING>",
          "fields" : [ {
            "name" : "field2",
            "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
            "doc" : "bigint",
            "default" : null
          }, {
            "name" : "field2",
            "type" : [ "null", "long" ],
            "doc" : "bigint",
            "default" : null
          }]
        }
      ]}
    ]}
  ]}
}
```

Whats going wrong here? I'm pretty sure exactly this worked some days ago, so I conjectured that Microsoft switched to another patch version of HDP for HDInsight clusters which has another Avro or Hive version, but I haven't found any indications to that.

I found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15316 which seems to be pretty similar problem (on the same Hive version).

Does anybody know whats going wrong here and what I could do to fix this problem or as a workaround?